# How to retrieve negative values using JAMOD

Tags: java, modbus

I'm using Jamod to retrieve values from Modbus device. It works fine for normal values. When I try to retrieve negative value from register, it generates some random value.

Code:

```
private float getData (String  address, int count) {
float sum = 0.0f;

request = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(Integer.parseInt(address), count);
response = new ReadMultipleRegistersResponse();
request.setUnitID(1);
response.setUnitID(1);
request.setHeadless();

try {

    response = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) execute(connection, holdingRequest);

    for ( int i=0; i<registerCount; i++) {
            sum = sum + response.getRegisterValue(i);
    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
return sum;
}

private ModbusResponse execute(SerialConnection connection, ModbusRequest request) {        
    try {
        transaction = new ModbusSerialTransaction(connection);
        transaction.setRequest(request);
        transaction.execute();
        return transaction.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In modbus devices register size is mostly of 16 bit, so when you get values from register using jamod, you should take care of storing it into proper datatype.

eg. in register 0x1000 value stored was -12456, and when we read it say

```
int value = readRegister(0x1000);

it returns me value = 53080
```

so int is  32 bit, by changing datatype of int(32 bit) to short (16 bit) returns original negative value

```
short value = (short) readRegister(0x1000);
it returns value = -12456
```

hope it answers your problem!